# Why should use 'venv' when use Flask framework?

Tags: python, web, flask

Nowadays I've studied Flask Web framework for developing app. And I use python for programming language.
I searched how to use the Flask then the most people say that when I use flask, I should activate virtual environment so called `venv`. I got the curiosity at that point why I should use virtual environment when I use Flask Web framework. I appreciate to answer this from everyone. Anybody help me please!

Comment: You can go through this: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Comment: virtual environments are almost always a suggestion and not a requirement, but they can help keep your development environment clean by separating dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I would even use `conda` (miniconda3) and not just the python-specific virtual environment (`conda` can handle all other dependencies, too, even system dependencies).

Using virtual environment is very good, because your global system environment with its dependencies - stays unchanged as long as you work inside a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

You don't have to use a virtual environment at all.

## What is a virtual environment?

A virtual environment is a Python environment such that the Python interpreter, libraries and scripts installed into it are isolated from those installed in other virtual environments, and (by default) any libraries installed in a “system” Python, i.e., one which is installed as part of your operating system.

The `venv` folder is a common name for the folder of the virtual environment.